# Nesting tables not working

Tags: html, css, html-table, nested

I'm trying to "nest" (not sure if that's the right word) some tables. I don't want a table in each cell, rather the ability to organize the table with appropriate headings. I'm told by my engineers that I can't simply style a table to "look" nested, rather it would be better if each header wrapped the children rows and cells.

Here's a screen shot of what it should look like:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="container">
    <table class="zebra">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Procedure</th>
                <th>Units</th>
                <th>Charge</th>
                <th>Avg. Charge</th>
                <th>As %</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="level1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <i class="doctor"></i>John Dorian
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tbody class="level2">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <i class="address"></i>Southern Hills Hospital
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tbody class="level3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="level1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <i class="doctor"></i>John Dorian
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tbody class="level2">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <i class="address"></i>Southern Hills Hospital
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tbody class="level3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="level2">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <i class="address"></i>Southern Hills Hospital
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tbody class="level3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="level2">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <i class="address"></i>Southern Hills Hospital
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tbody class="level3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>99234</td>
                        <td>Chest XRay</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                        <td>40.00</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So you can see I'm nesting `tbody` within other `tbody`s. This renders in Chrome fine. In fact it's how I want it to look.

BUT

When I inspect element, I see that Chrome (and Safari and Firefox) basically say "nuh uh" and break the nested `tbody`s out. See here:

Any ideas how to accomplish what I'm trying to get here?

[image]

Comment: Have You tried to wrap each <tbody> in <table> ?

Comment: A tbody cannot have a tbody child

Comment: Yeah I'm guessing that's the case. Just tried to validate it. Didn't pass. Is there anyway accomplishing this without JS?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over complicating the solution.  Given the screenshot you provided, no nesting is really required.  Your engineers are wrong, you can style a table to look nested.

1. Remove the nested tbodys, and use `tr` with a class associated to it's level.
2. Style each level according to it's depth.  I target the first `td` in each `td` to apply a `padding-left` value to make it look nested.

Here is the Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/msV2U/

CSS:

```
body { font-family: arial; }

table { width: 100%; }

thead th { background-color: #f6f6f6; padding: 5px; }
table td { border: 1px solid #DDD; padding: 5px; }

tr.level1 td { font-weight: bold ;}
tr.level2 td:first-child,
tr.level3 td:first-child { padding-left: 25px; }
```

And the HTML:

```
<table class="zebra">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Procedure</th>
            <th>Units</th>
            <th>Charge</th>
            <th>Avg. Charge</th>
            <th>As %</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="level1">
            <td colspan="6">
                <i class="doctor"></i>John Dorian
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level2">
            <td colspan="6">
                <i class="address"></i>Southern Hills Hospital
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level1">
            <td colspan="6">
                <i class="doctor"></i>John Dorian
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level2">
            <td colspan="6">
                <i class="address"></i>Southern Hills Hospital
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level1">
            <td colspan="6">
                <i class="doctor"></i>John Dorian
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level2">
            <td colspan="6">
                <i class="address"></i>Southern Hills Hospital
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level3">
            <td>99234</td>
            <td>Chest XRay</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly how I had done the markup and style when they told me this wouldn't work. So actually I checked with the engineers and it turns out that there was some other functionality that I wasn't privvied to that changes the situation a bit. I'll mark this as closed. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Well, I still want to know why Chrome decides to unnest my tables. I kinda need it for an email campaign and with email you need to use nested tables, unfortunately.

Comment: Chrome is breaking it out because you need to wrap the nested `<tbody>` tags with another `<table>`. It's not valid to just have nested `<tbody>` tags with no direct parent.

Comment: Valid markup would be: `<table><tbody><tr><td>  <table><tbody><tr><td>nested cell</td></tr></tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody></table>`

Answer (score -1):

New info came to light and this question no longer applies. Thanks.